# F-Droid v1.15.2: archive.newpipe.net/fdroid/repo: Error getting F-Droid index file => null All other repos didn't create errors

Tags: f-droid

I'm trying to add the custom F-Droid repository, and when I do I am getting this error?

> archive.newpipe.net/fdroid/repo: Error getting F-Droid index file => null

All other repos didn't create errors.

What am I doing wrong? I've tried a few times always the same thing. Each time I remove the repo. How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me,

1. Remove the NewPipe installed by F-Droid.
2. Remove and reinstall repo.

**If this gives you any problem, try separating the Hash from the URL when you add the Repository**

Then I was able to install the new NewPipe. Not sure what happened here. My guess is this was a change with the [F-Droid v1.15.2](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/org.fdroid.fdroid/),

> - Stay safe by checking repo index signatures and APK hashes